# How to set timezone based timestamp to get current date and time in C#?

Tags: c#, datetime

I am running a C# application in which I get the current date and time using DateTime.

```
DateTime currentTime = DateTime.Now;
```

When I run this code on my local machine, it returns the UTC +05:30 (local time). However, when I deploy this as a solution on the server, it returns some other time -> 11:50 AM something.

How do I set the value of current time so that it reflects time from one timezone. More specifically the Indian time zone.

Comment: use `DateTime.UtcNow`

Comment: You can convert the DateTime object into whatever time zone you want. But seriously, you shouldn't be dealing with time zones except for date/times that will be displayed to a user, and in that case, you want it to be the user's local time zone. Otherwise, always use UTC time, obtainable with `DateTime.UtcNow`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. @CodyGray I am using DateTime.UtcNow